# SQLCMD is not executed through asp.net application

Tags: vb.net, iis, remote-server, sqlcmd

I have asp.net application to upload database on a remote server using SQLCMD, but the command is not executed. If I execute it in cmd directly it works fine.  Here is the code

```
        Dim output
        Dim result As String = ""
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        'p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c sqlcmd -S " + serverIP + " -U " + sa + " -P " + P@ssw0rd + " -Q" + Chr(34) + " RESTORE DATABASE " + txtDatabaseName.Text + " FROM DISK=" + Chr(39) + dbPath + Chr(39) + " with move " + Chr(39) + oldmdf + Chr(39) + " to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" + mdf + Chr(39) + ", move " + Chr(39) + oldLog + Chr(39) + " to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" + txtDatabaseName.Text + "_log.ldf'" + " CREATE Login " + txtDatabaseUser.Text + "  WITH PASSWORD = " + Chr(39) + txtDatabasePassword.Text + Chr(39) + ";" + Chr(34)
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c sqlcmd -S " + ddlDatabaseServerURL.SelectedValue + " -U " + txtDatabaseServerUsername.Text + " -P " + txtDatabaseServerPassword.Text + " -Q" + Chr(34) + " RESTORE DATABASE " + txtDatabaseName.Text + " FROM DISK=" + Chr(39) + dbPath + Chr(39) + " with move " + Chr(39) + oldmdf + Chr(39) + " to 'F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" + mdf + Chr(39) + ", move " + Chr(39) + oldLog + Chr(39) + " to 'F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" + txtDatabaseName.Text + "_log.ldf'" + " CREATE Login " + txtDatabaseUser.Text + "  WITH PASSWORD = " + Chr(39) + txtDatabasePassword.Text + Chr(39) + ";" + Chr(34)

        Dim strFile As String = "C:\inetpub\vhost\Endpoint_Website\Endpoint_EB\mylog.txt"
        Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            sw.WriteLine(
        IIf(fileExists, p.StartInfo.Arguments, Nothing))
        End Using
        p.Start()
        output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: FYI - By creating dynamic SQL statements based on user input you make your application vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: What database are you using? Can you show the declaration of p which I presume is Process?

Comment: am using MSSQL 2014 and is process
`Dim p As Process = New Process()`